# JHipster many to many relationship with extra field

Tags: jhipster

I've generated a `ManyToMany` relationship between two entities but I need to add a extra field in the join table

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cliente_modulo",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "modulo_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Modulo> modulos = new HashSet<>();
```

In this way is added a new table in database but is not created a new entity.

How to generate a `ManyToMany` relationship that adds a entity with extra field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `ManyToMany` relation you can setup a `OneToMany` between *Cliente* and *ClienteModulo* and a `ManyToOne` between *ClienteModulo* and *Modulo*.

This should generate the join table as before but also the model entity and everything else you need.

Something like:

```
entity Cliente{}
entity ClienteModulo{}
entity Modulo{}

relationship OneToMany {
  Cliente{clienteModulos} to ClienteModulo{cliente}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  ClienteModulo{modulo} to Modulo{clienteModulos}
}
```

Add the properties you need to *ClienteModulo*.

Comment: Should I create manually ClienteModulo or using generator tool?

Comment: I personally would use the generator tool, that's what jhipster is for. But I don't know what constraints you have on this project, it's your decision to make really :)